# loading issue css Images and js in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When class Admin loads the by default index() called. the css and js load on dashboard view, but when i load post **add_post** CSS, JS and image not loading.
i put the same code on both view files. dashboard and add_post
this is my controller.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
  }

  public function Post()
  {
    $this->load->view('add_post');
  }

}
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/timesofeducation';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html', 'captcha', 'string');
```

when i load **index()** the css url showing when inspect element.
http://localhost/timesofeducation/css/style.css

but when i load. **post()** the css url showing when inspect element.
http://localhost/timesofeducation/Admin/css/style.css

**Admin** Class automatically added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed `/` in base_url. Try this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/timesofeducation/';
```

and make sure you have use resource link like

```
<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i put the / . but it not working. the problem is that when i go for any method in a Class the base_url() auto takes the class. after base url. mention above . question